# Property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, pydev, pylint

I have a property decorator so:

```
def Property(f):  
    """
    Allow readable properties without voodoo.
    """
    fget, fset, fdel = f()
    fdoc = f.__doc__
    return property(fget, fset, fdel, fdoc)
```

Used (for example) so:

```
    @Property
    def method():
        """"""
        def fget(self):
            return some expression...
        return fget, None, None
```

So my question is about the python way of doing this. Pydev complains about

> "method `method` should have self as
>   first parameter"

And pylint gives me

> Method has no argument

I know I can turn off this error message in pydev, but Im wondering if there is a better way to manage methods that do not take self as a parameter, something I can do better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [@staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to create a method which does not receive an implicit first argument. Doesn't Python's [@property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator already do what you want?

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 'foobar'

>>> foo = Foo()

>>> foo.bar
<<< 'foobar'
```